# Issue with baking high to low poly normal map

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I'm attempting to bake the high poly version of the sculpt into the normal for the low poly version. The high poly hand was imported as an fbx into the low poly scene. The low poly hand has been unwrapped.

Any help would appreciative, even if it's just getting me to ask the right questions when trying to problem solve in blender.

Screenshot: 
[image: blender bake settings]

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/df7h2htauk2ncxy/hand-badnormal.blend?dl=0

Comment: Well since the inherit site design is awful and I can't reward a reputation bounty, I'll offer a real one. Tell me what's wrong and/or fix the file and I'll cash app or paypal you. Shoutout to Duarte for being a mod, over being of help.

Comment: just curious, what rep would you use if you could offer a reputation bounty?

Comment: The rep I would use is in previous comment. Purchasable rep. I want to get this answered its completely stonewalled me and the only thing to come from this "community" are people stirring up any topic they can that aren't the problem at hand.

Comment: For what it's worth, the solution to this ended up being something so fundamental to 3D modeling. That I'm convinced that no one in this community, especially the mods, have even basic understanding of anything in regards to blender or 3D modeling.